# How to create permission to read/view files?

Tags: rest, post, google-drive-api, google-apis-explorer

How do I pass the permissions hash or json? correctly and maybe access token?

`https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/file_id/permissions`

This is the body I want

```
{
  "role": "reader",
  "type": "user",
  "emailAddress": "cratagg@gmail.com"
}
```

But I don't know how to include it in postman. I've been trying many ways but none seems to work. I couldn't either with the https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ - I may not know how to formulate the request.

The only thing that worked was the https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create "Try this API" section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create?apix=true) feature shows the HTTP implementation if expanded

[image]

So, in your case, the request would be:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/[FILEID]/permissions?key=[YOUR_API_KEY] HTTP/1.1

Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "role": "reader",
  "type": "user",
  "emailAddress": "cratagg@gmail.com"
}
```

Whereby you need to specify the API key and the FILEID.